# URL is not hitting the server(mongodb)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

i want to get the object from my collection based on the quesListName which i send as a param to the server
here is my service

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.service('getCandidateInterviewListService', function($http, ajaxServiceManager) {        
    var sUrlQuestions = "http://localhost:4000/onboardvue/questions/qListQuestions/";        
    return {

        fnGetQuestions: function(qListName) {
            return ajaxServiceManager.fnQuery({
                sUrl: sUrlQuestions,
                sMethod: "GET",
                oData: null,
                oParams: {
                    quesListName: qListName
                }
            });
        },
    };
});
```

below is my schema

```
var QuestionsSchema = new Schema({
topicName: String,
quesListName: String,
question:String
```

});

and the query which i wrote to get the object based on quesListName is

```
exports.query = function(req, res) {
Questions.find({quesListName:req.query.quesListName}, function(err, questions) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
    }
    return res.status(200).json(fnData(questions));
});
```

};

but i am getting 500 error

Comment: Why you mention mongodb?

Comment: because database what i m using is mongodb

Comment: Have you started your `mongod` server in your code i am not seeing any connection

Comment: yes i have connected to mongo db

Comment: Is there anything such as `qListName` defined in the code?